# Send new data from Server to client over websocket

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, apache-kafka

We have a scenario where we need to update(send notification) to a X user belongs to a Y (subscribe)group on activity of other group members in real-time.

We decided the tech stack as -
MongoDB -- store user activity in MongoDB, 
Kafka - Push activity event in Kafka (Messaging Queue) as well, 
Spring Boot --- Backend API, 
Angular2/Android/iOS -- Front End,
Websockets -- real-time data update

So, whenever there is an activity from user, it will be logged in both Mongo and Kafka.

Client  will subscribe to Websocket /activity/{group-id}

Websocket will talk to kafka through kafka consumer and send notification to client if there is any new message in kafka.

My Question is -
How do I keep Kafka consumer process listening to Kafka-topic (I know how to read messages from Kafka) and send if any new message is there to client over socket.

In other words, One way communication from Server to Clients,of subscribed group.

Thanks
Pari

Comment: You consume your messages with a consumer and you push your notification to client via your web socket. That's all

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Can you point me to sample code. I am not able to find suitable example except chat app. Which is more like two way communication rather one way server to client.